# Unable to create layout while getting details from DB

Tags: android, android-layout

I have problem with creating layout like this: [image: Layout]

I get from my database informations like Id, brand and model and link to images. How to create this layout and execute img url and put it into "frame"?

Here is my ActivyLayout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.app.demo">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/items_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And my custom row_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/item_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/item_brand"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="26sp"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/item_model"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom adapter for this and custom layout file like below mentioned code. Use volley to make network call and get data from API in JSON and then bind it to your custom adapter. If you need example in detail then follow this. http://androidkeeda.com/android-custom-listview-with-pagination-like-facebook-feed-using-volley

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profilePic"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"></ImageView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:text="id"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:text="Brand"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:text="Model"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Create a file in your drawable folder like below.

**border.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >


    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/colorAccent" />

</shape>
```

Comment: One more question, How to add drawable to border.xml so it will look like this: [img](https://imgur.com/a/QczMR)

Comment: Put this image into drawable folder and add android:src="@drawable/img" in you ImageView tag.